# How to create a link to edit a specific field value of a node inside views using views php?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-views, drupal-field-collection

I am using views php by adding a custom php code field to my view display, so I have the `$data` variable available. Inside the custom php code, I am rendering fields that have been added with a field collection relationship:

```
<?php
global $user;
$html = array();

if (count($data->field_field_poi_link) > 0) $html[] = 'foobar';

if ($user->uid != 0 && arg(0) == 'node' && node_access('update', 'foobar', $user)) {
  $nid = arg(1);
  // $html[] = '<a class="inl_edit" href="'.$data->_entity_properties['url'].'/edit?destination=node/'.$nid.'">edit</a>';
  // $html[] = '<a class="inl_del" href="'.$data->_entity_properties['url'].'/delete?destination=node/'.$nid.'">delete</a>';
}
print join("\n",$html);

?>
```

Before the **entity api update on 10th Jan** the `$data->_entity_properties` array contained this:

```
'_entity_properties' => 
  array (
    'url' => 'http://localhost:8888/project/field-collection/field-poi-link/39',
  ),
```

but now, it contains nothing like that. I cant edit that one specific entry.

How can I create a link to edit one specific value for each field collection's entered field data like `http://localhost:8888/project/field-collection/field-pois/74/edit` inside a views php field?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's better if you use [views hooks](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_hooks/7); 
That's more safer than views_php.
As an example you could see [hook_views_pre_execute](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_execute/7)